# interpreting boolean value in PHP with if statement

Tags: php, boolean

The following form is returning true all the time, even if the domain is available. Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

```
<?php
function domainAvailable($domain){
$results = @dns_get_record($domain, DNS_ANY);
return empty($results);
}
if (isset($_REQUEST['domain']))  // check to see if form has been submitted
{
$domain = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['domain'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

$httpdomain = 'http://' . $domain;

    if (domainAvailable($httpdomain) == true){
        echo "$domain is not available.";
        if (domainAvailable($httpdomain) == false){
            echo "$domain is available!";   
        }
    }
}
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<div>
<label for="domain name">Suggest a Domain:</label> <input type="text" name="domain" /><br />
<input type="submit" />
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by untangling your ifs:

```
if (domainAvailable($httpdomain)){
   echo "$domain is not available.";
} else {
   echo "$domain is available!"; 
}
```

Also, you probably have your strings backwards

```
if (domainAvailable($httpdomain)){
   echo "$domain is available.";
} else {
   echo "$domain is not available!"; 
}
```

Then, get rid of this line:

```
$httpdomain = 'http://' . $domain;
```

Your domainAvailable function is probably going to always return true because `http://` is not part of a valid domain name

The call to htmlspecialchars is probably going to cause false negatives as well.

Put it all together:

```
<?php
#CLI debugging:
if(empty($_REQUEST['domain']) && !empty($argv[1]))
    $_REQUEST['domain'] = $argv[1];

function domainAvailable($domain) {
    $results = @dns_get_record($domain, DNS_ANY);
    return empty($results);
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['domain']))  // check to see if form has been submitted
{
    $domain = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['domain'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

    if (domainAvailable($_REQUEST['domain'])) {
        echo "$domain is available.";
    } else {
        echo "$domain is not available!";
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ php scratch.php google.com | more
google.com is not available!
$ php scratch.php googleasdfasdf.com. | more
googleasdfasdf.com. is available.
```

Comment: PS. htmlspecialchars doesn't mess anything up

Comment: any chance you can explain the reason for including the #CLI debugging?

Comment: "htmlspecialchars doesn't mess anything up" -- only if your input doesn't include special characters.  Try a non-ascii domain like `Bücher.ch` or `президент.рф`.  You probably need to implement punycode to really make those work, but `htmlspecialchars` is going to get in your way regardless.

Comment: I put the CLI mode in 'cause it was easier for me to work/test that way :)